# Problems using Tail (Node.js module) to read file as it is updated

Tags: node.js, file, minecraft

I'm trying to use Tail (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail) to export Minecraft server log data to Discord (The discord bot part works, so I have excluded it from here).

If I say something in the game and then check "latest.log", it has been changed accordingly. However, using this script, the bot only sees a change if I open "latest.log" in notepad, it doesn't work otherwise. The bot will recognize changes as long as "latest.log" is open in the background, which is an annoyance but not too big of a deal.

However, my friend is the one who I was making this for, and for him Tail only updates the moment he opens "latest.log". Which means he would need to keep opening up that file for Tail to see it, instead of just letting it run in the background.

```
Tail = require('tail').Tail;


var fileToTail = "C:/Users/user/Downloads/logs/latest.log";

tail = new Tail(fileToTail);

tail.on("line", function(data) {
//Working code that sends data
});
tail.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});
```

What could be causing the discrepancy between the two of us, and what can I do so that the bot can see the file changes without the user opening the file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are multiple caveats regarding how `watch` works, particularly across OSs. How the file is written to may also come into play.

Comment: first I would suggest to debug the issue using `fs.watch` and see what kind of events are firing. Maybe use [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) because again `fs.watch` is unstable accross OS.

Comment: I should add that we're both using Windows 10, so there shouldn't be a problem with different OS's.

Comment: I would suggest as well to write a little test with fs.watch. How does it behave, when latest.log is changed? Then you may report an issue agains the tail package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `chokidar`, you should pay attention to whether you are using `fs.watch` Vs. `fs.watchFile`. If using `fs.watch` you not successfully catch changes (which might be what you are experiencing).

See below from official docs for `chokidar` options:

> usePolling (default: false). Whether to use fs.watchFile (backed by
> polling), or fs.watch. If polling leads to high CPU utilization,
> consider setting this to false. It is typically necessary to set this
> to true to successfully watch files over a network, and it may be
> necessary to successfully watch files in other non-standard
> situations. Setting to true explicitly on MacOS overrides the
> useFsEvents default. You may also set the CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING env
> variable to true (1) or false (0) in order to override this option.